# Remove class if clicked outside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make it so that if I click outside a `paragraph` element then the background color is removed? Note I want to it to only be able to highlight one `p` at a time.

```js
$('p').click(function() {
    $('p').removeClass('yellow');
    $(this).addClass('yellow');
});
```

```css
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit tenetur sequi amet sit dolorem, nulla inventore quo cum ad distinctio aut nesciunt reprehenderit dolorum quidem animi unde aspernatur. Esse, eius!</p>
            <p>Deleniti vitae rerum eum saepe eaque tenetur libero, omnis nisi sapiente dicta est repellat, provident placeat quia inventore, at architecto quisquam, pariatur minus quam magni totam praesentium dignissimos. Incidunt, sequi.</p>
            <p>Fuga cupiditate consectetur, corporis architecto, doloremque impedit ullam quia praesentium voluptatibus molestiae dolor sint, odio amet atque culpa fugit blanditiis ea nam repellat necessitatibus. Aliquam voluptate fuga quo, omnis mollitia.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
$('p').click(function(e) { 

$('p').removeClass('yellow'); //If there is any p with class yellow, it removes that
  $(e.target).closest('p').addClass('yellow'); //This find closest target when you click, in our case current paragraph(p)

});
$(document).click(function(e){ //Here is when you click in your entire document
  if($(e.target).closest('p').length==0) { // If click is not paragraph
     $('p').removeClass('yellow');  //It removes this class existed from any paragraph
    }
  

})
```

```css
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit tenetur sequi amet sit dolorem, nulla inventore quo cum ad distinctio aut nesciunt reprehenderit dolorum quidem animi unde aspernatur. Esse, eius!</p>
<p>Deleniti vitae rerum eum saepe eaque tenetur libero, omnis nisi sapiente dicta est repellat, provident placeat quia inventore, at architecto quisquam, pariatur minus quam magni totam praesentium dignissimos. Incidunt, sequi.</p>
<p>Fuga cupiditate consectetur, corporis architecto, doloremque impedit ullam quia praesentium voluptatibus molestiae dolor sint, odio amet atque culpa fugit blanditiis ea nam repellat necessitatibus. Aliquam voluptate fuga quo, omnis mollitia.</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain what is happening on each line of code in your jQuery?

Comment: I commented almost each line on my JQuery code. Take a look, I edited snippet! Hope you understand! :)

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi there's a caveat in your code that you did not considered - which will make your script **fail**, and that's: if any other unrelated  element on the page also uses `event.stopPropagation()` in that case nothing will happen - cause `document` will never register that event - and will not *un-highlight* the paragraphs - even if `p` was not clicked.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I did not think about it! Thanks for reminding me! I edited again my snippet. :)

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi even after your edit the problem still persists cause you bound your event to `document` > which never registered that event since some element used `event.stopPropagation();` You can easily test this by adding a random element that prevents the click to reach `document`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```js
$("p").click(function (e){
    $("p").removeClass("yellow");
    $(this).addClass("yellow");
});

$(document).click(function (e){
    var element = $("p.yellow");

    if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0)
        element.removeClass("yellow");
});
```

```css
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="yellow">Text text text</p>
<p>Text text text</p>
<p>Text text text</p>
```

Comment: @mohammad I want to just have one paragraph selected in yellow at a time. Your method works but it is highlighting all paragraphs in yellow

Comment: @mohammad I have pasted in your code and now nothing changes if I click a p element

Comment: @ewcoder Excuse me for previous answer. I updated my asnwer related to question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a listener to the `<body>` and check if the click was onto a `<p>`:

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).is('p')) {
        $('p').removeClass('yellow');
    }
    else {
        $(event.target).addClass('yellow');
    }
});
```

Comment: `body` can never become `p` so `if(!$(this).is('p')) {` makes no sense